# remove an element from an array in an foreach not yet used

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of events per day, ordered by date but not by event contenders, and I want to merge elements that are back to back.

```
day,       user,   #days
```

---

```
Monday,    user1,  1
Monday,    user2,  1
Tuesday,   user2,  1
Tuesday,   user1,  1
Wednesday, user1,  1
Wednesday, user3,  1
```

should give:

```
day,       user,   #days
```

---

```
Monday,    user1, 3
Monday,    user2, 2
Wednesday, user3, 1
```

I use foreach on the array and if it is a full day event I use and recursive function to look for days from the same user that are the day after and remove the element if found using this function.

```
function nextday(&$array,$name,$date,$aantaldagen){
$date = strtotime($date + "1 days");
foreach ($array as $key=>$item){
    //echo("<br/>".date('Y m d',$date)." vergelijk met ".date('Y m d',strtotime($item['DTSTART'])));
    if( date('Y m d',$date)==date('Y m d',strtotime($item['DTSTART'])) && $item['SUMMARY'] == $name ){
        $aantaldagen = nextday($array,$name,$date,($aantaldagen + 1 ));
        echo("aantal dagen = ".$aantaldagen);
        unset($array[$key]);

    }
}
$array = array_values($array);
return $aantaldagen;
```

}

and I get the following output:

```
day,       user,   #days
```

---

```
Monday,    user1,  3
Monday,    user2,  2
Tuesday,   user2,  1
Tuesday,   user1,  2
Wednesday, user1,  1
Wednesday, user3,  1
```

Do I have to remove the elements before the first foreach, i don't want to go trough the array again, or am I doing something wrong?

edit:

so the global code looks something like this:

```
$events = <an array of events> (example element = (['DTSTART']=>20140821, ['SUMMARY']=>user1, ['DTEND']=>1)) // the 1 is standing for a full day
foreach( $events as $event){
  ...
  if($event['DTEND']==1){
    $numberofdays = nextday($events,$event['SUMMARY'],$event['DTSTART'],0)
    Date: <?=date('D, j M Y',strtotime($event['DTSTART'])); if ($aantaldagen>0)echo("<br/>tot ".date('D, j M Y',(strtotime($event['DTSTART']." +".$aantaldagen." days"))))?>
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: _I want to merge elements that are back to back_. Pls clarify what you want to get

Comment: see the table after _should give:_

Comment: I seen that. But it's unclear how you get this result

Comment: I don't, I get the last table that is exactly my problem.

Comment: The problem is that you can't explain in general words what you want to get and how to get it

Comment: so i want to get the output after _should give_ and I get the output after _Iget the following out put_ and I edited the global code the function nextday is defined above

Comment: No one want to look at your code and obscured desired results unless you explain **verbally** what you want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt know how you are getting the data so i cant write the exact code.... But i can tell the logic

```
$printed = array();
$new = $user.','.$day;
if(! in_array($new,$printed))
{
    echo $value;
    $printed = $user.','.$day;
}
```

If the user is already printed it will no print again :)

Comment: won't this give problems if a user has multiple events that are a few days apart lets say a user has an event on Monday and an event on Friday?

Comment: thank you this is a nice workaround, if at the end of the day I don't have and better answerer I will mark this as the best anwenser